# spring boot & Spock

Tags: spock, spring-test

I have a  springBootVersion = '2.3.2.RELEASE' app and I would like to use Spock for my unit and integration tests.  I have this for Spock in my Gradle:

```
  testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'junit', module: 'junit' //by both name and group
    }

  testImplementation group: 'org.spockframework', name: 'spock-core', version: '1.2-groovy-2.4'
 testImplementation group: 'org.spockframework', name: 'spock-core', version: '1.2-groovy-2.4'
 implementation group: 'org.codehaus.gmavenplus', name: 'gmavenplus-plugin', version: '1.6.3'
```

And my first test is pretty simple:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = PrototypeApplication.class)
class PrototypeApplicationSpec extends Specification {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext context

    def "test context loads"() {
        expect:
        context != null
    }
}
```

But when I run it, the ApplicationContext is null:

```
> Task :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileGroovy NO-SOURCE
> Task :processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileTestGroovy
> Task :processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :testClasses
> Task :test FAILED

Condition not satisfied:

> context != null |       | null    false
> 
> Condition not satisfied:
> 
> context != null |       | null    false
```

It's been awhile since I used Spock, so I am not 100% that my libraries are correct but it does try to run, just can't seem to load the context.

Comment: Please upgrade you Spock version 1.2-groovy-2.4 is really old, but the same goes for the Spring version as well.

Comment: Yes I need to, but that will likely require Gradle and other changes as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include `spock-spring` in your project.

Replace on of the `spock-core` duplicates with `spock-spring` inside your `build.gradle`:

```
testImplementation group: 'org.spockframework', name: 'spock-core', version: '1.2-groovy-2.4'
testImplementation group: 'org.spockframework', name: 'spock-spring', version: '1.2-groovy-2.4'
```

Comment: Thank you, I sure didn't see that typo.